# jquery not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple animation made in jQuery but for some reason doesn't work in IE8 and previous versions. here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('.circle.pink').animate({display: 'block'}, 800, function(){
                    $(this).animate({right: 446}, 1200, 'easeOutExpo')
                });

                $('.circle.green').animate({display: 'block'}, 2000, function(){
                    $(this).animate({right: 20}, 800)
                });

                $('.circle.blue').animate({display: 'block'}, 2800).animate({right: -100}, 800, function(){
                    $(this).css('z-index', '4')
                }).animate({right: 0}, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
            });
```

here's the html:

```
<div class="circles-wrap">
         <div class="circle green"></div>
         <div class="circle pink">
            <article class="intro">
                <span class="logo left"></span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>                                   
            </article>
         </div>
         <div class="circle blue"></div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.circle{
    width:514px;
    height:514px;
    display: block;
}

.circle.pink{ background:url('../images/c-pink.png'); position:absolute; right:0; z-index: 3;}
.circle.blue{ background:url('../images/c-blue.png'); position:absolute; right:0; z-index: 2;}
.circle.green{ background:url('../images/c-green.png'); position:absolute; right:0; z-index: 1;}
```

Any idea why it doesn't work? The commas seem to be in the right place.

Thanks in advance,

Mauro

Comment: Can you provide the html that goes with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**display** is not a css-property you can use inside animate(), animate expects properties with numeric values. 
Maybe this is throwing an error which IE forces to quit.

Comment: Right -- Firefox usually bypasses attribute errors like these, IE does not. You can use a callback function after your animation fires where you then can hide the element, or you can animate the opacity to 0. after you set the duration of your animation, you should add ", function() { $(element).hide(); }"... or add in the opacity animation.

Comment: yes I didn't think about it. Thanks! I used instead another property with numeric value. Btw IE is still the stupidest browser ever! :)

Comment: Stupidest ever for not dealing with your bad coding? It's like walking into a restaurant and ordering lobster. They tell you there is no lobster on the menu and you complain. You go to another restaurant and order the lobster and they bring you veal instead, yet you happily tuck in content that you got brought something out, even if it's not exactly what you wanted.